# TypeError: is_valid() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, django, forms, view, django-2.0

***strong text***I have write models and form files successfully but still showing some error in views after passing argument is the self is not defined after defining self it is showing NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_bound

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import personal_data,professional_career
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .form import detail , details2

def cricket_form(request, self=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=detail(request.POST)
        form=detail2(request.POST)

    if detail.is_valid(self) or detail2.is_valid(self):
        form.save()

    context ={

    }
    return render(request,"template/createform.html",context)
```

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: here is my code'

Answer (score 1):

the Error `NoneType` object has no attribute `is_bound` is 
because you are calling `is_valid` method on the form class `detail` but not the `detail instance` object `form` object.

change your code to:

```
form1 = detail(request.POST) # Better to user uppercase class name(Detail)
form2 = detail2(request.POST)
if form1.is_valid() or form2.is_valid():
    ...
```